# EF Core Scaffold DbContext

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm having problem with scaffolding `DbContext`. I'm using latest `.NET Core 1.1.0 SDK` and I'm following this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db

But when I run following command in Package Manager Console: `Scaffold-DbContext "<connection-string>"  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models` I get exception.

**project.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": [
        "dnxcore50"
      ]
    }
  }
```

**Exception**

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 
'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, TableSelectionSet tableSelectionSet)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, TableSelectionSet tableSelectionSet)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.SqlServerScaffoldingModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, TableSelectionSet tableSelectionSet)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineeringGenerator.GetMetadataModel(ReverseEngineeringConfiguration configuration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineeringGenerator.GenerateAsync(ReverseEngineeringConfiguration configuration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContextAsync(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas, IEnumerable`1 tables, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.<ScaffoldContextImpl>d__22.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source, Int32& length)
   at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Comment: Yes: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7068

Answer (score 1):

The current workaround for this is to execute the scaffolding in an executable project that is configured as the startup project in your solution.